# Using jquery $.ajax on window.onerror in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a script going on ff and chrome (don't care about safari) where when there is a javascript error it send an email.

It works on FF & chrome.

On ie8 I see the console.log or alert I added in the success of the ajax call but the call itself is never made, this makes me crazy that it actually goes into the success function

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"jserrorhandler.php",
        data:"message="+msg+"&url="+url+"&line="+line+'&from='+settings.from+"&website="+settings.website,
        success: function(){
            if(window.console) console.log("Report sent about the javascript error")
        }
    })
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just sayin' you should make sure `console` has `log` method as well `('console' in window && 'log' in console)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, IE was caching my ajax request, thats it...

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    cache:false
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will make a difference but you are missing a semicolon after the ajax call.

Comment: Semicolons in js are inferred. Without a return to an empty function, in this case, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: I was aware of that but I remember reading that this behavior differs with browsers. So I wasn't sure how IE8 handles it.

Comment: It's good practice to include the semicolon rather than letting the browser decide what to do with syntactically incorrect JavaScript.  You can use lint to make sure you're writing correct code.